# Java File into ArrayList and referencing the ArrayList to another class

Tags: java, class, arraylist

So i have been coding a project in Java and have come across a pause while trying to reference an array list to another class. The first bit of code is the class I am trying to reference the `ArrayList` too. The second is where I am creating the `ArrayList`s.

```
import Game.App;

public class WordPuzzleGenerator {

    public WordPuzzleGenerator() {
        if (Game.SizeOfPuzzle.currentRows == 4){
            threeLetterWordList
        }else if (Game.SizeOfPuzzle.currentRows == 5){
            maximum = 12482;
        }else{
            maximum = 1310;
        }
    }
```

---

```
    Scanner threeLetterScanner = new Scanner(File("3LetterWords.txt"));
    ArrayList<String> threeLetterWordList = new ArrayList<String>();
    while (threeLetterScanner.hasNext()){
        threeLetterWordList.add(threeLetterScanner.next());
    }
    threeLetterScanner.close();

    Scanner fourLetterScanner = new Scanner(File("4LetterWords.txt"));
    ArrayList<String> fourLetterWordList = new ArrayList<String>();
    while (fourLetterScanner.hasNext()){
        fourLetterWordList.add(fourLetterScanner.next());
    }
    fourLetterScanner.close();

    Scanner fiveLetterScanner = new Scanner(File("5LetterWords.txt"));
    ArrayList<String> fiveLetterWordList = new ArrayList<String>();
    while (fiveLetterScanner.hasNext()){
        fiveLetterWordList.add(fiveLetterScanner.next());
    }
    fiveLetterScanner.close();
}
```

Comment: If I understood well, you have to use getters.

Comment: So what exactly is the problem?

Comment: @Mureinik As shown in the wordPuzzleGenerator class the first if statement I am trying to reference to the ArrayList which has been created in App.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a variable inside the class like:

```
public class WordPuzzleGenerator {

    ArrayList<String> threeLetterWordList = new ArrayList<String>();
    //...
    public List<String> getThreeLetterWordList() {
       return threeLetterWordList ;
    }
}
```

THen you can just call myGenerator.getThreeLetterWordList(); to get your list.

Comment: Ah okay that will work thanks you for that @breakline